# Cannot read property 'func' of undefined react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I am getting this error while implementing date picker
I take help from these URLs:

1. http://dev.quri.com/react-bootstrap-datetimepicker/
2. https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/18941xp52l

> ```
> render() {
>     const { date, format, mode, inputFormat } = this.state;
>     return (
>       <DateTimeField
>         dateTime={date}
>         format={format}
>         viewMode={mode}
>         inputFormat={inputFormat}
>         onChange={this.handleChange}
>       />
>     );
>   }
> ```

Comment: thats because firstly the repo is very old and in its source code its trying to import `Proptypes` from react which is now not longer shipped bundled, try using different lib or probably download Proptypes module and change the source code

Answer (score 0):

`react-bootstrap-datetimepicker` is an old package. It tries to import `PropTypes` from `React` module, however, the export was removed by React team from version 16+.

I suggest you to use alternatives like [react-dates](https://github.com/airbnb/react-dates).